# "ImportError: DLL load failed" when importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I get an error when trying to import Tensorflow (v.2.2):

In order to make sure that there are no issues with the Tensorflow installation, I re-installed all the relevant packages in a virtual environment. The error stack that results is the following (both in the virtual and in the original environments)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\cifar_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\cifar_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\cifar_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module(**'_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'**, fp, pathname, description)
File "c:\anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "**c:\anaconda\lib\imp.py**", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

**Is it possible to tell What DLL is failing to load exactly?**

**Edit**:

If I downgrade to Tensorflow v2.0  the import doesn't fail, but all scripts need to be re-written

If I downgrade to Tensorflow v2.1, the import still fails.

It would be really helpful if somebody could point at what the issue might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading to Tensorflow v1.13.1, which I am using in another machine, results in a collection of warnings, but no errors.

Ridiculous altogether

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and there didn't appear to be any smoking gun solution - none of them worked in isolation. ***For anyone truly desperate***, this is what I did that cumulatively solved the issue. Note, I am working in an Anaconda Virtual Environment (venv):

1. I ensured the C++ redistributable was correctly installed, as suggested by [xdhmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356887/xdhmoore) in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259900/tensorflow-installation-on-windows-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tens) related post. After uninstalling and reinstalling it, to be certain, I upgraded Visual Studio from 2019 to 2022.
2. I updated Conda to the newest version.
3. Thereafter, I created a wholly new venv. However, I did not use Conda to install any packages except the mandatory packages that it uses to create the environment. I then installed tensorflow using pip (and all other desired packages that I was having issues with pip as well).
4. Due to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512#issuecomment-425096387) GitHub post, I copied `msvcp140.dll` from the `System32` folder to my venv's `DLL` folder.

Thereafter, tensorflow works again.